# Can I re-assign to a var inside a SwiftUI view?

Tags: ios, swiftui

The commented-out line is the one I actually want to execute.

After trying all sorts of things, it appears I can't reassign to a variable inside a view.

Above the line I want to execute, I tried the simplest reassignment to the var newSlotSize but as soon as I do I get the error message "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions"

If I comment out that lime compilation completes ok.

Any suggestions on how I can get the wanted line to execute?

```
            VStack {
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    Spacer()
                    ZStack {
                        let numSlots = kidsMaxSlots
                        let gwidth = geometry.size.width
                        let gheight = geometry.size.height
                        let gameplayArea = geometry.size.height * gwidth
                        let slotsArea = gameplayArea / CGFloat(numSlots)
                        let slotSize = slotsArea.squareRoot()
                        let widthInSlots = Int(geometry.size.width / slotSize + 0.5)
                        let heightInSlots = Int(geometry.size.height / (slotsArea.squareRoot()) + 0.5)
                        var newSlotSize = geometry.size.width / CGFloat(widthInSlots)
                        let newNumSlots = widthInSlots * heightInSlots
                        let myShift = newSlotSize / 2
                        if newNumSlots < numSlots {
                            newSlotSize = 1.0
//                            newSlotSize = geometry.size.height / CGFloat(heightInSlots)
                        }
                        ForEach(gameplayDisplayArea.slotsArray.indices){ mySequence in
                            gameplayDisplayArea.slotsArray[gameplayDisplayArea.slotsArray[mySequence].id].slotImage
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: newSlotSize - 5, height: newSlotSize - 5)
                                .background(Color.green.opacity(0.4))
                                .position(
                                    x: myShift + CGFloat(mySequence % Int(gwidth / newSlotSize)) * CGFloat(newSlotSize),
                                    y: myShift + CGFloat(Int(CGFloat(mySequence) / CGFloat(widthInSlots))) * newSlotSize
                                )
                        }
                        VStack {
                            HStack {
                                Text("\(geometry.size.width)")
                                Text("\(geometry.size.height)")
                            }
                            HStack {
                                Text("slot size: \(slotSize)")
                                Text("new slot size: \(newSlotSize)")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .background(Color.red)
                .padding(.horizontal, 20.0)
                .padding(.bottom, 160.0)
                .frame(maxWidth: 800, maxHeight: 960)
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing the `if` with a ternary operator so you only assign a value to `newSlotSize` once?

Comment: @Paulw11 - Yaay, that did the trick. Thanks Paul :)